# Symbol on the border of pages when printing

Tags: printing, hplip

I am using Debian (unstable) and I try to use a hp printer (hp Color Laserjet CP3525dn). I installed the last version of hplip.

I have a problem when I try to print a US layout document in A4 paper. The print add a symbol useful when you want to cut the paper :

[image]

I have this symbol at every corners. How can I get rid of it?

Comment: Are you sure it's your printer and not the document or the software you're using to print?

Comment: As Gilles said, this is part of the document, not the doing of the printer. Depending on what format your document is, there *are* commands to crop it before printing so it's the right size.

By the way, for anyone searching for this, or similar issues: this is a crop mark.

Comment: @Alexios Like I said, it happens only for documents with US paper Layout. The A4 layout works fine. And I have also problems with some pictures the printer refuses to print. Documents which don't work are pdf and mostly, preprints coming from a publisher.

Comment: PDF is dumbed down Postscript (which is Turing complete and a surprisingly good programming language on its own), but it still has plenty of smarts. It could well be the crop marks appear on demand, or they're just outside the print area of the A4 sheets (I don't see how this could happen, though... A4 is wider than Letter, but Letter is taller than A4 — I'd assume you'd see some crop marks all the time). You could ask the publisher to see if they do anything ‘weird’ with their PDFs.

Comment: @Alexios I have the crop marks only for US letter (and not on A4 paper)...